# How do I display a different image everytime the image is clicked?

Tags: java, html, css, smartphone

I am completely new at this so if you want to direct me to something informative and educational i completely understand.

I have a file full of images and i want them to display in an app one after the other when they are clicked.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question is lacking needed context -- what type of program is this? What have you tried? What isn't working? Can you show us your present code? Are you sure that you mean Java and not JavaScript -- they are completely different you know? Please tell us the important details, and soon as the question risks being closed as too broad or unclear without these details.

Comment: To expand in what Hovercraft said, it is customary here not to include greetins or thanks in the question, as all the content should be relevant to it. So, I would have deleted everything but one line. That is all the information you are giving us.

Comment: do u want the images to be randomly displayed???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using html js and css:

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/dec2mpbv/

html:

```
<img src="http://picture-gallery.dnspk.com/albums/userpics/10001/normal_1124750273-15.jpg" id="images"/>
```

js

1. make an array of images u want

   ```
   var currentImageIndex = 0;

   var images=[
       'http://picture-gallery.dnspk.com/albums/userpics/10001/normal_1124750273-15.jpg',
       'http://images7.alphacoders.com/408/thumbbig-408758.jpg',
       'http://images6.alphacoders.com/410/thumbbig-410020.jpg',
       'http://picture-gallery.dnspk.com/albums/userpics/10001/normal_1127034390-11.jpg'
   ];
   ```

   document.getElementById('images').setAttribute('src',images[0]);

   ```
   document.getElementById('images').onclick = function(){
       if(currentImageIndex<images.length-1)
           currentImageIndex++;
       else
           currentImageIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('images').setAttribute('src',images[currentImageIndex]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of your image path and use a method that increment the index of the list, that return a different image. You can also use a radomizer of this index

Comment: I appreciate the help Harsh